# Add Class for div element using JSLT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jstl

I have :

```
<div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3 ${product.getProducer().getName()} all">
```

and : list of product (Products). Product(id, name, price...)

Can someone tell me how to add class to  with product price. For each price of product, add a class respectively to .

For example : Product : $100 => Add `class="lt100"` to div.
 $100 - $200 => add `class="100to200"` to div. I tried to use JSTL to do that :

```
<c:forEach items="${product.getProductSizes()}" var="item">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${item.getPrice() < 100 }">
                    <!-- What now :( ??? !-->                   
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

But i dont know what's next and JSTL really can do that ?

Sr my bad english .Tks for reading !

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${product.getProductSizes()}" var="item">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${item.getPrice() < 100 }">
               <div class="lt100"></div>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${item.getPrice() > 100 and item.getPrice() < 200 }">
               <div class="100to200"></div>
            </c:when>

        </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need jstl for that, just simple string appending thats all:

```
var ClassToAdd = "lt"+ ${item.getPrice()}
document.getElementsByClassName("${product.getProducer().getName()}")[0].class=ClassToAdd;
```

Comment: "lt" just used if price < 100, price can be : <100, 100-200, 200-300 and >300.

Comment: yes, but thats not my point :) you can write whatever you need in there